# Problems when attaching a second ultrasound sensor (HC SR04)

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, hc-sr04

I am working on an obstacle avoiding robot. It uses an ultrasound sensor to avoid obstacles, but currently has trouble avoiding objects that are diagonal to it. Thus, i want to add a second ultrasound sensor, and alternate their readings. I am testing the code, which should look right and then leftn and return the distances. The code worked for just one ultrasound.  and it is a follows:

```
#include <NewPing.h>  
#include <Servo.h>  


#define trig_pin1 A1 //analog input 1
#define echo_pin1 A2 //analog input 2
#define trig_pin2 A3 //analog input 1
#define echo_pin2 A4 //analog input 2
int distance1 = 100;
int distance2 = 100;

#define maximum_distance 200 //sensor function
Servo servo1; //our servo name
Servo servo2;
NewPing sonar1(trig_pin1, echo_pin1, maximum_distance);
NewPing sonar2(trig_pin2, echo_pin2, maximum_distance);
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  servo1.attach(11); //our servo pin
  servo1.write(90);
  servo2.attach(6); //our servo pin
  servo2.write(90);

  distance1 = readPing1();
  distance2 = readPing2();
  delay(100);
  distance1 = readPing1();
  distance2 = readPing2();
  delay(100);
  distance1 = readPing1();
  distance2 = readPing2();
  delay(100);
  distance1 = readPing1();
  distance2 = readPing2();
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
    int distanceRight = 0;
  int distanceLeft = 0;


        distanceRight = lookRight();
    delay(300);
    distanceLeft = lookLeft();
    delay(300);
  }
}

int readPing1(){
  delay(10);
  int cm = sonar1.ping_cm();
  if (cm==0){
    cm=250;
  }
  return cm;
}


int lookRight(){  
  servo1.write(50);
  delay(500);
  int distance1 = readPing1();
  delay(100);
  servo1.write(115);
  return distance1;
}

int readPing2(){
  delay(10);
  int cm = sonar2.ping_cm();
  if (cm==0){
    cm=250;
  }
  return cm;
  }
int lookLeft(){
  servo2.write(170);
  delay(500);
  int distance2 = readPing2();
  delay(100);
  servo2.write(115);
  return distance2;
  delay(100);
}

I get the following error: 
'readPing1' was not declared in this scope
```

and I get the same error for the readPing2 function. Why could this be?

Comment: tip: you can simplify your code by using `if (cm==0) cm=250;`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had an extra "}" after the void loop function. The code worked as expected after removing it